# Magento2: Can we customize the FedEx shipping price?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, fedex

Can we customize the FedEx shipping price?

My Magento v2.0.17

Comment: No, not shipping price but you can add handling fee  - An optional handling fee can be added to the amount charged by FedEx, which is not visible during checkout. If you want to charge a handling fee.

Comment: Do you want any elaboration on FedEx ?

Comment: FedEx shipping price can we apply state wise?

Comment: Wait let me look in to that

Comment: Do you have any fedex merchant ?

Comment: Yes, We have the FedEx merchant account. But now we test on sandbox account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83894/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-masud-shaikh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FedEx configuration**

If you have set up a FedEx sandbox and want to work in the testing environment, set Sandbox Mode to "Yes."

> Remember to set Sandbox Mode to "No" when you are ready to offer FedEx
>   as a shipping method to your customers.

[image]

**Package Description and Handle Fee**

> - Select the Packages Request Type to the option that best describes
>     your preference when splitting an order into multiple shipments:

- Divide to equal weight (one request)
- Use origin weight (few requests)

> - Select the type of Packaging typically used to ship products from your store. Options include:

- FedEx Envelope
- FedEx Pak
- FedEx Box
- FedEx Tube
- FedEx 10kg Box
- FedEx 25kg Box
- Your Packaging

> - Set Dropoff to the pick-up method that will be used for delivery. Options include:

**Regular Pickup**

- If you have a **high volume of shipments**, it can be cost effective
  to make arrangements with FedEx for regular pickups.

**Request Courier**

- You must call and request a FedEx courier to pick-up shipments.

**Drop Box**

- You must drop off shipments at your nearby FedEx drop box.

**Business Service Center**

- You must drop off shipments at your local FedEx business service
  center.

**Station**

- You must drop off shipments at your local FedEx station.

> - Set Weight Unit to the unit of measurement that is used in your locale. Options include:

- Pounds
- Kilograms

> Enter the Maximum Package Weight allowed for FedEx shipments. The default FedEx maximum weight is 150 lbs. Please consult your shipping
>   carrier for more information. We recommend using the default value,
>   unless you have made special arrangements with FedEx. See also:
>   Dimensional Weight.
>   [image]

**Config sales shipping methods fedex delivery methods**

[image]