# Magento2: How to apply charges on multi pick-up address in FedEx?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, shipping-address, fedex

I have added FedEx shipping method and I want to apply charges on multi pick-up address in FedEx shipping method.

Suppose one customer order 2 products and it is pick-up location also different then charges apply pick-up location wise.

I have discussed with FedEx support team he said you can apply multip pick-up charges on one order to the customer using API.

Anyone can tell me how to customize FedEx API?

My Magento v2.0.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anyone can tell me how to customize FedEx API?

- Adding a flag for api
- For FedEx API to know that it needs to return shipping estimate it
  needs to be given a “`ReturnTransitAndCommit`” flag.
- Storing the response data API

**you can find multiple references for Magento Fedex**

1. https://www.xadapter.com/setting-up-magento-2-0-fedex-shipping-extension/
2. [Magento2: Can we customize the FedEx shipping price?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/magento2-can-we-customize-the-fedex-shipping-price/244538#244538)
3. https://inchoo.net/magento/make-magento-fedex-api-show-shipping-estimate/